# How exactly is a form closed/disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I want to use multiple windows in my code, I normally do it like this:

```
Window w = new MainWindow();
w.Show();            
this.Close();
```

but today, I discovered I could do this:

```
Window w = new MainWindow();
this.Close();
w.Show();
```

And I was a bit surprised, so I'm wondering what exactly does `this.Close` do? Yet from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close.aspx), it says the application will stop running (shut down) if the last window was just closed, so how come?

However, this does **not** work in WinForms, only WPF.

Comment: WPF has Window, Page, and UserControl but no form.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing a window causes any windows that it owns to be closed. Furthermore, closing a Window may cause an application to stop running depending on how the `Application.ShutdownMode` property is set.

The default value for it is `OnLastWindowClose` which means the application will close only after closing the **last created window**. At the point `this.Close()` in your example you already have 2 windows (is't no matter whether a window opened or hidden).

You can see it in WPF sources, `Window`s constructor adds newly created window to `Application.Windows` collection. And `Window.Close()` method executes the following code:

```
if (((App.Windows.Count == 0)
    && (App.ShutdownMode == ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose))
    || ((App.MainWindow == this)
    && (App.ShutdownMode == ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose)))
{ 
    App.CriticalShutdown(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you could as well but **last created window** in bold. That makes sense, I wonder why this change was made in WPF though?

Comment: I'm still wondering something though, If I remove w.Show() the program ends, why is that then if it shouldn't close when there's still a created window?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Are you sure that program actually ends? If you remove `w.Show()` the program just stays in processes without any opened forms. I just tested and it is so.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are merely changing the order of:
1. Showing the new Window
2. Closing the current Window
Since the actual rendering happens anyway after you exit from your code - there should be no difference. Regardless of the order of #1 and #2, you are never out of windows (although hidden, the second window exists), so the application will not shutdown.

Consider the following code below. Although the Show happens 3 seconds after the close of the first window, the application will not exist. Once the user click on the 'Rotate' button, the first window will disappear for 3 seconds, and a new window will appear.

XAML:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Rotate" Width="80" Height="50"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
    MainWindow w = new MainWindow( );
    this.Close( );

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer( );
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 3 );
    timer.Tick += ( o, a ) => {
        ( (DispatcherTimer)o ).Stop( );
        w.Show( ); 
    };

    timer.Start( );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but why is it that if there's no `w.Show()` it exits, yet the window is still there?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata - it is there, just hidden. A UI element doesn't have to be visible to exist. "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?" maybe not, but if a Window exists and nobody can see it - definitly exists.

Comment: Aren't you contradicting yourself?